# Finding repeated groups of letters in the Kasiski examination

Tags: cryptanalysis, frequency-analysis

While doing the Kasiski examination I came to a problem. If there is the following group of letters in the cipher: **AA** and later on a group **AAA** is found. Does it count as two repeats or just one? And if one, then when does it start, with the first **A** or with the second?